# Передача имени класса для вызова в рантайме

Tags: scala, hadoop

Работаю на проекте на котором **не могу** вносить фундаментальные архитектурные правки.
Код проекта написан так, что приходится создавать однотипные структуры, подход такой:
Скопировал код -> поменял название класса -> передал в него экземпляр класса **X** -> Запустил.
Однако при запуске данного класса из под узи потока в hadoop есть возможность передать путь до **X** в качестве строки. Родилась закономерная идея - передавать экземпляр **Х** в рантайме. Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность это делать в Scalа? Или может есть более элегантное и правильно решение для такого кейса?

Comment: Если известно название пакета класса и самого класса, то его можно подгрузить по время выполнения. Делается как и в Java, через `Class.forName`. Элегантность решения зависит от, но runtime-компиляцию используют довольно редко, в основном для подключения JDBC-либы.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin
Получил аналогичный ответ на вопрос в англоязычном сегменте, только более развернутый :
[pass-a-class-name-as-string-argument-to-create-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028226/pass-a-class-name-as-string-argument-to-create-instance)